# Preventing duplicate data with locking or transactions?

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

In our application, when a user creates an order we get the next order # as follows:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(REPLACE(orderNum, 'SO', '') AS SIGNED)) + 1 FROM orders
```

The problem is that because the customer is getting busier, we are starting to see orders that are created at exactly the same time which results in duplicate order #'s.

What is the best way to handle this?  Should we lock the whole orders table or just the row?  Or should we be doing transactions?

Comment: Why not let MySQL do the order number generation for you by making the order a [auto_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)ing primary key?

Comment: using max() to generate the next id is flawed from the start and will either be incorrect when you have concurrent transactions or will not scale. Use the built-in features of the DBMS to generate the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extra table with just one field which has the auto_increment attribute.
Now every time you need a new order number you call a function that will create a field in this table and return the result of last_insert_id(), which you then can use as an order number (just make sure to set the auto_increment counter of the table higher than your greatest order number).

Comment: The order # is separate of the primary key in the orders table.  So you can orderID=1, orderID=2 but they could both have the same order # - that's the problem.  I'd like to avoid having to add a table for this.

Comment: @drschultz There are other ways to do this, but they all involve locking and transactions of sorts which you asked to avoid. Inserting a row into a table with auto_increment is the only atomic instruction I know of that will avoid fiddling with those types of things. Whether that requires an extra table depends on your database layout which we don't know anything about.